# Actual Audio Standards in the Industry

Tags: production, standard, broadcast-standards, list, documentation

Where can I find docs about audio standards in the industry (max DB, Sampling rates...).
Best if they are classified by domain (TV, Cinema, Video games, music).
Actual standards would be well appreciated (I claasify audio cd standards as old...).

my question is generic so don't hesitate posting your answer even for 1 particular domain.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: The EU are developing a bunch of standards for media. Here's one on loudness: https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/tech/tech3342.pdf

Comment: Thx. Nice.Would you like to have it listed on the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Real Life delivery formats**

44.1/48 kHz @ 16/24 bits

**Files formats**

[Specification of the Broadcast Wave Format (BWF) - EBU](https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/tech/tech3285.pdf)

[RF64: An Extended File Format for Audio - EBU](https://tech.ebu.ch/publications/tech3306)

**Standard Mixing Levels for Movie Theater, DVD, TV, Internet, Radio and Games**

[gearslutz thread](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/229741-standard-mixing-levels-movie-theater-dvd-broadcast-tv-commercials-etc.html)

**Interfaces**

[AES/EBU](https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/tech/tech3250.pdf)

**TV :**

[ATSC A/85](http://atsc.org/recommended-practice/a85-techniques-for-establishing-and-maintaining-audio-loudness-for-digital-television/)

[EBU R128](https://tech.ebu.ch/loudness)

**Video Game**

[Sony ASWG](http://gameaudiopodcast.com/ASWG-R001.pdf)

**Apple iTune**

[Mastered for iTune](https://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/docs/mastered_for_itunes.pdf)

**Recommendation for Loudness of Audio Streaming and Network File Playback**

[Technical Document AES TD1004.1.15-10](http://www.aes.org/technical/documents/AESTD1004_1_15_10.pdf)

**AoIP**

[AES 67](http://www.aes.org/publications/standards/search.cfm?docID=96)

[SIP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt)

among many others ;-)

Answer (score 1):

ATSC/85 is the US broadcast standard.  They have a really well done and extensive PDF at [ATSC.org](http://atsc.org/standards/atsc-standards/)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding levels there is an article by Jeff Towne http://transom.org/2011/levels/ – excellent explanation of every aspect of this complicated area. It's not so easy to say "max DB standard".

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your hands on the NBC, CBS, and major broadcasters spec sheets. Ive seen them for delivery requirements for broadcast.